# Method invocation error when using PSCredential in Powershell

Tags: powershell, tfs, automation, scripting

I will start by saying that I have successfully tested this script when running locally on my laptop against a remote dev server.

However, when I have migrated the script to our TFS server, I am now encountering the below (sanitized) error message.

```
2019-06-10T18:46:05.8256626Z Generating script.
2019-06-10T18:46:05.8257313Z Formatted command: . 'E:\***.ps1' -username "***" -password "***" -servername "***" -ScriptPath "***" -SourcePath "***" -DestinationPath "***" -CleanupFlag "***"
2019-06-10T18:46:06.0290179Z ##[command]"C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'E:\***.ps1'"
2019-06-10T18:46:06.7520864Z Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential] does not contain a method named 'new'.
2019-06-10T18:46:06.7521292Z At E:\***.ps1:5 char:1
2019-06-10T18:46:06.7521480Z + $CredentialSec = [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::new($username,$PWsec)
2019-06-10T18:46:06.7523016Z + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2019-06-10T18:46:06.7523588Z     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
2019-06-10T18:46:06.7524614Z     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
2019-06-10T18:46:06.7525361Z  
2019-06-10T18:46:06.8602349Z ##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
```

The script is attempting to Invoke-Command (to run a different script) on a remote system. It appears to be messing up at the section where it creates a credential from the username and encrypted password.

This is the code that I'm attempting to execute:

```
param($username, $password, $servername, $ScriptPath, $SourcePath, $DestinationPath, $CleanupFlag)


$PWsec = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force
$CredentialSec = [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::new($username,$PWsec)

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $servername -Credential $CredentialSec -FilePath $ScriptPath -ArgumentList $SourcePath, $DestinationPath, $CleanupFlag
```

Comment: i can't remember the exact details, but I think using "::new" to invoke constructors is a recent-ish addition to PowerShell. try runnig $psversiontable on your machine and the tfs server to check the versions installed, and also try using "new-object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$PWsec)" instead of the "::new" style.

Comment: ah, here we go... https://learn-powershell.net/2014/09/07/more-new-stuff-in-powershell-v5-a-new-way-to-construct-things/ - added in PowerShell 5 - see the "What’s NEW" section. i'll turn this into an answer if it works...

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per mcclayton's suggestion in the comments... because the new server is running an older version of Powershell, it worked when I changed from this format:

```
$CredentialSec = [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::new($username,$PWsec)
```

To this format:

```
$CredentialSec = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$PWsec)
```